# How to limit file upload size in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, file-upload

I want to save bandwidth and restrict the size of uploaded files to our webpage. The problem is that I can set the maximal size of uploaded file (e.g., 1 MB) but a user can select 50 MB file and can upload it to find out that PHP really doesn't accept files of this size -- the uploading is totally unnecessary.

Can I prevent this somehow?

(I can check file size in Javascript but not all browsers support this. Flash is an option but it's not universal either).

Thanks!

Comment: You can configure your webserver to deny such large incomming requests earlier before those reach PHP. Additionally you can configure PHP with a maximum file upload limit. What have you done so far? What is your current configuration (take a look into phpinfo() for example), see as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757111/large-file-upload-errors-with-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I limit users from uploading more then 5MB to the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476350/how-can-i-limit-users-from-uploading-more-then-5mb-to-the-server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`LimitRequestBody` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) in `.htaccess`:

Example (setting a 1Mb limit). Create/modify your `.htaccess` file (in your webroot, or higher), and add:

```
LimitRequestBody 1048576
```

When the limit is exceeded, the request will be **interrupted**. The user will get a response similar to:

> 413 Request entity too large

---

Also: **Rule 1: Never trust the client!** You should always do such checks server-side, because the client can easily circumvent your JavaScript checks, and do anything which is not restricted by the server.

Comment: HTTP Error 413 Request entity too large